# UIImageView spinning image

Tags: xcode, animation, uiimageview

Is there any way to put a sliding image in a `UIImageView`? I mean getting a photo, zooming in on the photo, and when the app is running slide the zoomed up photo. when it reaches the end of the photo, it starts again from the other side. like if it was a spinning globe, instead a spinning image. or even a bigger image, that slides in a smaller `UIImageView`, sliding in diagonal or horizontal. I tried looking up on the internet, but didn't find it.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Look at this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587636/animate-rotating-uiimageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to move the image within the `UIImageView`, you could make the `UIImageView` larger than the window and move it by manipulating its frame property, perhaps using an `NSTimer`.

Comment: could try, it would give the same effect